# Upsampling a non equally spaced signal

Tags: convolution, upsampling

I have a signal that has not an equally spaced sampling time $T_s$, and I would like to upsample it with an equally spaced $T'_s$.
My first approach was to interpolate it with a spline and then obtain the new signal with the sampled time I want. But this approach is not properly signal processing. I would appreciate any suggestion to techniques I could use.